# Inexplicable growth in data-base file

Tags: mysql

I've got several webservices running on my serving, including MySQL. For some reason, the space MySQL is taking grows exponentially. The ibdata1 file was about 20GB in size and he was taking up all the space I had on the partition. So i enlarged the partition, but the file grew even more up to about 30GB...

What's causing this growth? How can I stop it? And how can I reverse the growth so I can continue to work (since the partition is full again...)

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to have what I'm going to call a 'big ass database'?  (What I really mean is: your question is extremely vague.  A million things could make that file grow.)

Comment: I would guess that if you stop inserting stuff, it will stop growing.

Comment: That's the point... I'm not inserting stuff. It grew like 10GB in a few hours... I deleted most of the logs and cache-tables, but the size is still unchanged...

Comment: May be your server has viruses

Comment: Is MySQL logging to a table, perchance?

Comment: This question really belongs on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'd monitor all of the tables in the system, and their row counts. That way you can focus on what tables are growing. As @eggyal said, it could be you are logging to a table (slow query, general log, apache), or it could be that you are subject to an external force filling your database...

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the previous comment, a lot of reasons could generate this issue. Errors being logged to some table and not being cleared up? Saving large binaries to the database? etc.

you might start investigating using `SHOW TABLE STATUS` which is documented [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) so that you narrow down which table is using storage most.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I've got multiple databases, so how do I know which one to select?

Comment: why not create a sql script which investigates the table for each of them? you can get the name of the databases with `SHOW_DATABASES` and get the calculated size for each table of each database dumped to a service table so that you get the summary.
you can also use the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html)